# SQL query exclude rows if having two different values

Tags: sql, group-by

Basically my select statement returns below:

```
ID     Status

100      1
100      2
101      1
```

What i'm looking for is to return if a ID having status as 1 and if the same ID has another status ID as 2 then exclude both

In Short results as below:

```
ID     Status

101      1
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Can there be more than 2 possible values for Status e.g.  1,2,3,4,5?

Comment: No only 2 possible values 1 & d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query returns ID values that occur only once.

```
SELECT ID
FROM t
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

It should be sufficient for the sample data you provided. If there are other cases then let me know.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97a2cf/1)

Answer (score 1):

You gonna need subquery and `NOT IN` here.
The following would work if you have column `status` as `INT` datatype

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE status = 1 
       AND ID NOT IN (
              SELECT ID 
                FROM table 
               WHERE status = 2
       );
```

Answer (score 1):

Making a generic query, which will remove all duplicated rows, not only for a particular ID :

```
  select ID 
     from table where ID NOT IN
      (select ID from table GROUP BY ID HAVING count(Status) > 1) 
     /* Subquery will fetch ID's having multiple entries*/
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0429cb/2)

Comment: +1) it is not fair that you lose the point because of true answer.

Answer (score 0):

The CTE 'IDs' retrieves all IDs which have single record in DB. This is then joined to original table to return the result as a pair (ID, Status)

```
;with IDs as
(
select ID
from yourtable
group by ID
having count(*) = 1
)
select i.ID, y.Status
from yourtable y
inner join IDs i on y.ID = i.ID
order by i.ID
```